# How to generate Etruscan 2D complex manifold space vectors using the eigenvalues of the compact Riemannian metric tensor?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

In short, I wish to generate a set of points in a subset of the 2D Euclidean plane. For those who want to know, I plan on using it to generate a quasi-homomorphic mapping with the following underlying sub-generator (Tsiolkovsky, 1903):

$$\Delta v = v_e ln \frac{m_0}{m_f}$$

Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: This question has nothing at all to do with reverse mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply the identity matrix and convolve with a Gaussian filter of order $n$:

$$ \left[\begin{matrix} 00 & 01 & 02 \\ 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 20 & 21 & 22 \end{matrix}\right] $$